# windows batch file / get last word in a line

Tags: batch-file

I have a weird case in batch file.

I have a txt file named state.txt containing the following line :

```
State          ON
```

I need to read the "ON" word (it can be OFF as well), so I'm using the following simple batch file :

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2" %%a in (state.txt) do set word1=%%a
echo %word1%
```

when executing the batch file , I dont get any output , but when I change the "ON" or "OFF" word to any other word it's shown.

I'm confused here! what's the relation between ON/OFF and the output got.

Comment: If you would have read the help file for the `ECHO` command before posting your question you would have had a better understanding of what was happening.  You can read the help for any command by opening a command prompt and typing the command name followed by a forward slash and question mark. `echo /?`

Answer (score 2):

This is because `ON` and `OFF` are special inputs for `ECHO` which turn command-echoing on or off. Consider this:

```
SET VAR1=OFF
ECHO %VAR1%
SET VAR2=ON
ECHO %VAR2%
SET VAR3=TEST
ECHO %VAR3%
```

This will output:

```
C:\Windows>SET VAR1=OFF
C:\Windows>ECHO OFF
C:\Windows>SET VAR3=TEST
C:\Windows>ECHO TEST
TEST
```

You're not seeing the `VAR2`-part, because command-echoing is turned of with `VAR1`. Your seeing the `VAR3`-part, since `VAR2` turns it on again.

If you want to echo the words `ON` and `OFF`, you can do by placing a dot between `ECHO` and `ON` or `OFF`:

```
C:\Windows>SET VAR4=ON
C:\Windows>ECHO.ON
ON
C:\Windows>SET VAR5=OFF
C:\Windows>ECHO.OFF
OFF
```